# Broken Shimano Nexus 8 Gear Hub

Tags: hub, nexus, clicking

My HUb is a Nexus SG-8R31, 7 years and 3500 miles (5600Km) old. It has just developed a loud "clicking" noise when going forward, This happens both on and off the bike. It sounds like a broken ball bearing or pawl spring but I haven't dismantled it (yet).
Has anyone experienced the same problem and found the cause of this clicking? Is it repairable or do I have to replace the whole internal assembly?

Comment: Has it had an oil dunk device ever?

Answer (score 1):

it has never had an oil dunk - but it is just about to get one.
I have found out the cause of the broken hub!
I decided to dismantle the hub and found the cause almost immediately - it is a completely shattered ball bearing cage on the non-drive side of the hub. Cost of a new one - less than a fiver. Great relief.
So relieved in fact I have decided to service the hub myself and have sent for the special Shimano hub grease and "dunking" kit - at a cost of over £80!
It looks pretty straight forward (hopefully not famous last words).

Comment: It's very straight forward. Glad it was a simple issue. I will say that many people use gear oil in an improvised container with good success. The Shimano oil bath product is an okay buy for a shop that's going to get 30 uses out of each one, but is pretty painful otherwise. Personally I think that if one is going to get any of the special maintenance items for these hubs, the Nexus grease might be the more prudent place to start because it's fairly light and not really the same as other bike bearing greases. Lithium is probably a decent stand-in but i could see it causing pawl issues.